# Как создать краткое имя для remote

Tags: git

Добрый день.

На работе имеется сервер git, на нём юзер git. Папки к проектам расположены в

```
/home/git/www/public_html/001_project1{002_project2,003_project3 and etc.}
```

Т.е. в папке `public_html` лежат много разных проектов как репозитории, на них настроен апач, и каждая из папок является собственным поддоменом.

При выполнении git remote к рабочему серверу путь к проекту прописываем так:

```
git remote add git@server:001
```

то есть без указания полного пути проекта и указываем только какое-то краткое имя (первые 3 цифры).

Подскажите, как можно на своём собственном гит сервере настроить похожий remote add? Т.е. каким образом можно указать краткое имя проекта и без полного пути к нему? (Символьные ссылки не предлагать)

Comment: Опишите еще раз задачу. По ману я вижу, что нельзя не задать ремоуту имя (которое может быть любой длины).

Answer (score 1):

```
git remote add 001 git://git@server:001_project1.git
```